# Is this partial derivative evaluated correctly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $w=f(x,y)$, $x=3k$, $y=kh^2+2k$.

I got the solution that $\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial k\partial h} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial h}(3\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} + (h^2+2)\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}) = 0 + 2h \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}$

Is there an alternative solution?
Is the expression below evaluated correctly?

$\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial k\partial h}=\left(2hk\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)\left[3\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}+(h^2+2)\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial k} \enspace = \enspace 3\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + (h^2+2)\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} $$

And therefore,

$$ \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial h \, \partial k} \enspace = \enspace 6hk \, \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x \,\partial y} + 2h \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + 2kh(h^2+2) \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}$$

Note that the derivative of $w$ with respect to $x$, i.e. $\tfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$, can still be dependent on $y$. In other words $\tfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \tfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and thus $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \tfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} = 0$ is **NOT** true in general. Note furthermore, that in general

$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \enspace = \enspace \Big( \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \Big)^2 \enspace \neq \enspace \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}$$

One can always check if his solution is correct by calculating the inverse order, i.e. calculating $\tfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial k \, \partial h}$ instead of $\tfrac{\partial w^2}{\partial h \, \partial k}$. The solutions should coincide.